# Cite a book with unsrtdin style leads to double DOI in bib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I'm currently writing my thesis and there is a problem with DOI numbers and my preferred citation style `unsrtdin`.

The problem is that every book with DOI leads to a double link in the bib. 
When I use `article`I get one link and the DOI separately printed.

I would appreciate this "article" behavior for book as well.

What can I do to avoid this? It seems to be general problem with this style. It is not depending on the machine, document or what ever.

Here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505

Hope, you can help me!

Wishes, 
Mike

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,                                                                                             
    12pt,                                                                                                                                   
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                                                  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                      
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}                                           
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                          
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \cleardoublepage
    \bibliography{literatur}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

\blindtext
\cite{chemie-basiswissen}
\cite{euv-tomie-tin}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

The bib:

```
@BOOK{chemie-basiswissen,
    author = {H. P. Latscha and M. Mutz},
    title = {Chemie der Elemente, Chemie-Basiswissen IV},
    edition = {},
    editor = {},
    publisher = {Springer Verlag},
    howpublished = {},
    organization = {},
    year = {2011},
    pages = {188-190},
    note = {},
    isbn = {978-3-642-16914-4},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-16915-1}
},


@ARTICLE{euv-tomie-tin,
    author = {T. Tomie},
    title = {Tin laser-produced plasma as the light source for extreme ultraviolet lithography high-volume manufacturing: history, ideal plasma, present status, and prospects},
    journal = {Journal of Micro/Nanolithography, MEMS, and MOEMS},
    volume = {11},
    organization = {},
    year = {2012},
    number = {2},
    pages = {021109-1-021109-9},
    url = {http://stacks.iop.org/0741-3335/46/i=12B/a=047},
    issn = {1932-5150},
    doi = {10.1117/1.JMM.11.2.021109}
},
```

What I mean with "double links to DOI database" I mean the following shown in the pictures. 
[image: DOI link and DOI number separately shown]
[image: DOI link is shown twice]

I would appreciate at least the same behavior we get for articles for books as well. If not possible or to complicated, I would appreciate only the one DOI link shown for books. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide an example of an entry of type `@book` with a field of type `doi` that's giving you grief when used with the `unsrtdin` bib style.

Comment: What does `double link in the bib` mean? Construct a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate your point, please.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I added the MWE but it seems to be disappeared. Can't explain why but now it is there.

Comment: Thanks for editing the Code. I don't know whats wrong with this yesterday. It wasn't possible to make this shown as code. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon referring **unsrtdin.bst** file from [this link](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505), I found the similar kind of definition for `URL` & `DOI` under function `BOOK`.

Definition for `book`:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  ...
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  ...
}
```

Both `format.doi` & `format.url`'s definition are transform into `\URL`. Expansion for `format.doi` & `format.url` in below:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "\url{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{ urn missing$
     { doi missing$
          { url empty$
             { "" }
             { type empty$ NOT
                 { type #-1 #4 substring$ "mail" =
                   type #1 #4 substring$ "Mail" =
                   OR
                      { type$ "incollection" =
                          { "" }
                          { "\,Absenderadresse: \url{" url * "}" * }
                        if$ }
                      { "\url{" url * "}" * }%%   evtl. "URL" oder "<...>"
                    if$ }
                  { "\url{" url * "}" * }   %%   evtl. "URL" oder "<...>"
                if$ }
           if$ }
          { format.doi }
        if$ }
      { "\url{http://nbn-resolving.de/urn/resolver.pl?urn=" urn * "}" *}
    if$
}
```

Due to this reason, you are getting the double `URL` for `book`.

Hope `booklet` type can fulfil your requirement.

Modified BIB:

```
@BOOKLET{chemie-basiswissen,
    author = {H. P. Latscha and M. Mutz},
    title = {Chemie der Elemente, Chemie-Basiswissen IV},
    edition = {},
    editor = {},
    publisher = {Springer Verlag},
    howpublished = {},
    organization = {},
    year = {2011},
    pages = {188-190},
    note = {},
    isbn = {978-3-642-16914-4},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-16915-1}
},
```

BBL Output:

```
\bibitem[2]{chemie-basiswissen}
\textsc{Latscha}, H.~P. ; \textsc{Mutz}, M.:
\newblock \emph{Chemie der Elemente, Chemie-Basiswissen IV}.
\newblock \,Version:\,2011.
\newblock \url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-16915-1}. --
\newblock  188--190 S. --
\newblock DOI 10.1007/978--3--642--16915--1.
\newblock ISBN 978--3--642--16914--4
```

**EDIT** on July 14, 2017:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
...
  %%format.doi output%%Commented
  format.doi.urn output%%Modified to bring the requested DOI for Reference BOOK.
  format.url output
...
}
```

**EDIT** on July 17, 2017:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  ...
  format.url output
  format.doi.urn output
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. It removes the second DOI link but it also removes the publisher and this isn't nice at all, unfortunately. Is thee a possibility to edit this style and save it as an "own style"? What has to be edited to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Mike1993, yes, `format.doi` can be changed as `format.doi.url` within the definition of `FUNCTION {book}`, in order to bring the requested output. Kindly refer `Edit on July 14, 2017` on my answer.

Comment: @Kumeresh PS, thanks for the reply. It indeed was helpful. What I get is "URL + DOI-Code" for "Article" and with your modification I get "DOI-Code + URL" for "Book". Is it possible to have the same for books we have for article? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: This is possible by interchanging the position like `format.url output format.doi.urn output` under `FUNCTION {book}`. This is also updated in the answer. Please check.

Comment: @Mike1993 if the answer is helpful, please mark it as "answered". Then I'll add the bounty to Kumaresh PS.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It was helpful. I wasn't aware of the function of the part "format.url output". Thanks.